# Websocket endpoint stops working when HTTP2 + TLS is enabled

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, http2, spring-websocket, spring-cloud-gateway

We have a **WebSocket server** (written on Spring Boot) and it sits behind **Spring Cloud Gateway**

I've enabled `HTTP2` on spring boot for both the gateway and Websocket.

When TLS is disabled on both the gateway and Websocket, Websocket works without any issue. The client and server both can exchange messages.

The problem starts when I enable TLS on both sides. and the client invokes the WebSocket endpoint using `wscat wss:\\websocket-url`, the gateway logs show that the route is found, the request is successful and the connection is successfully upgraded to WebSocket. **However, there is no invocation on the Websocket Server side**. I don't see any errors on either side.

I enabled TLS debugging by setting

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl:handshake");
```

and I can see that **TLS handshake** is also successful without any issues. Can you please suggest what is wrong here?

This issue is producible with both Spring Boot v2 & v3. we are using Java 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't actually about Websocket, but dual `http/1.1` + `http/2` support.

WebSocket over HTTP/2 is not supported on most of servers including Netty and Tomcat. There is a proposed standard for the same which was recently updated, [RFC 8441](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8441), But I couldn't find any trace of such support in Tomcat or Netty.

I guess the issue here is about setup consistency - should we enable or disable `HTTP/1.1` when `HTTP/2` is enabled? In my case, `HTTP/2` wasn't needed and I disabled it. Websocket started working fine with TLS seamlessly.

Initially, I had configured Spring Boot app to enable `HTTP/2` (with TLS disabled). Even though this is not a pre-requisite for `HTTP/2`, but most of the servers won't upgrade the connection from `HTTP/1` to `HTTP/2` if TLS is not enabled. Hence Websocket API was working fine